# Compare 2 forks from github using local git?

Tags: git, github

I was given a zip file containing a directory structure, an app to fix. I've made many changes locally. Then it turns out that the actual source of this is a github project.

I want to be able to compare these locally on my laptop so I can figure out what differences there are between them before deciding which course of action to take for each difference.

Is this something I can do easily with git? I assume I can just clone the 'master' one from github and then create a new branch from the directory I was working in.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your assumption is correct. Clone the repo from github to a local directory, then do `git checkout -b my-branch`. Then simply overwrite the directory with your modified files. You can do a `git diff` at that point and see the changes, or you can commit the changes to your new branch and do a diff on the appropriate commits.

Comment: Thanks, maybe I jumped the gun here, I followed these instructions, created a new branch but don't see a directory created with the name `my-branch`.

Comment: A branch does not map to a directory; a branch represents all the directories at a particular point in time. When I say "overwrite the directory," I mean the local directory to which you cloned your repo to.

Comment: Ah, thanks for the prompt reply. The branch is a snapshot of the github repo, and suggest I then replace the files stored with in the checkout with the ones I have elsewhere?

Comment: Correct. Then a `git diff` will show the changes between your code and the repo.